# Java - understanding method signature

Tags: java, generics, methods, apache-kafka

What parameters should be sent to this Java method:

```
public void resume(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

More details [here](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#resume(java.util.Collection)).

I can see that `<TopicPartition>` is a Java Class with this signature:
 `TopicPartition(String topic, int partition)` 
but then after that, there is a keyword `partitions` in above Java method.

So is it 3 parameters or 2 or 1?

Please someone describe how should I read this kind of signatures.

Thanks.

Comment: The method expects a single parameter, a `Collection<TopicPartition>`.

Comment: Thanks. That single parameter looks like is a class of 2 parameters `TopicPartition(String topic, int partition)` . So is expectation to send String and int or a a collection (maybe a map) with these 2 values?

Comment: `TopicPartition(String topic, int partition)` is a *constructor*, not a *class*. Classes don't have signatures, only methods and constructors do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go through it step by step:

**First**, offcourse it is only 1 argument which is named 'partitions'

```
 public void resume(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

- `public` is the access modifier, which means this method is visible from everywhere
- `void` is the return type, which means there is no return value
- `resume` is the methods name/identifier

`Collection<TopicPartition> partitions` is a litte more difficult to explain:

The Interface 'Collection'followed by a Type (TopicPartitions) means that you can input any collection of TopicPartition objects to the method. E.g.:

```
List<TopicPartition> list = new LinkedList<>();
resume(list);  // valid, sind List or more exact LinkedList are a Collection

Queue<TopicPartition> qq = new PriorityQueue<>();
resume(qq);  // valid, sind Que or more exact PriorityQueue are a Collection
```

the syntax `Collection<Type>` is part of Java Generics, which you can have a closer looks at [this tutorial](https://www.protechtraining.com/content/java_fundamentals_tutorial-generics_collections).

What you call a keyword ('partitions') here is *no keyword at all*, but just the *name/identifier* of that input argument. You have to give each argument a destinct name - so you can identify it in the methods code.

in this example you can rename 'partitions' to anything you want, i would vouche for something like 'partCollection'

*void, return, public, private, static, class,* ... those are keywords.

**Second**, TopicPartition and the method you quote here is the constructor of the class TopicPartition, which needs 2 arguments: `String topic` and `int partition`  and not just a method.

The constructor is the method that gets called when you instantiate a class (create a object e.g. using the `new` keyword).

So to give you a more detailed example:

```
List<TopicPartition> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new TopicPartition("part1", 1));
list.add(new TopicPartition("part2", 2));
resume(list);  
// resume has now been called with argument of a list (which is a collection) 
// containing two TopicPartition objects whit part1, part2 and 1,2 as 
// construction arguments
```

Comment: Good answer. Only addition I'd suggest is a mention of the proper term for what he is describing. Namely "Java Generics". It would also be helpful if you add a link to some explanation that goes into more detail on Java Generics.

Comment: Thanks both. Just to drill down on `TopicPartition` for a moment. I can see it here (https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/TopicPartition.html) that it should be a class with this signature `TopicPartition(String topic, int partition)`. So based on that fact - is this a proper data structure `List<TopicPartition> list = new LinkedList<>();`?

Comment: @Gewure Do you maybe know how would Scala method look like for this? Maybe something like: `def kafkaResume(topicPart: scala.collection.immutable.List[TopicPartition]) = {
    consumer.resume(topicPart.asJava)
}` ? And if yes - how would someone call this method using Scala? 
Is a `List` right data structure for this (in Scala) or maybe a `Map`? Thanks.

Comment: @Joe i have no knowledge of scala (besides that i know that javas generics stem from scala originally) and none of kafka aswell - but to give you a hint: the method kafkaresume takes a immutable list <TopicPartition> as argument - so a List<TopicPartition> list = new ImmutableList<>(); would be the right Type in Java.